# Running unit tests and integration tests separately using MSTest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, integration-testing, mstest

We use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with tests written in MSTest. Both our unit tests and integration tests* are written in MSTest.

**By our definition, an integration test is an MSTest `TestMethod` that takes a while to run and/or calls out to external components such as a database or web services.*

I'm looking for a way of easily filtering out the integration tests so that only unit tests run without all the integration tests running too.

My ideas so far:

1. Mark integration tests with the `[Ignore]` attribute. This works but is a real pain when you do want to run the integration tests.
2. Assign a `[TestCategory]` attribute to the different test types. This allows them to be run separately but only through the Test View panel. You can't use CTRL+R, A (Run All Tests in Solution) or other similar shortcuts/hotkeys.
3. The integration tests are in a separate project, is there something that could be done to stop them running at the project level? As long as it's easy to toggle.
4. Write the integration tests in a different test framework, e.g. NUnit. This would keep them totally separate from a tooling point of view.

**Does anyone have any other suggestions? Are there any plug-ins that can help with this?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend having a different project (or projects) for integration tests because depending on your runner the only real way to run or not run tests across all runners is to include or not include a test class library.

But, I also recommend, if you're using MSTest, to use the TestCategoryAttribute to tag non-unit tests.  You can then "filter" tests to be run in Test View with MSTest.

Runners like Resharper and apparently TestDriven.net (http://bit.ly/tmtYC2) allow you to then filter-out those tests from general unit-test executions.

Comment: And, for what's it's worth, I don't use the MSTest runner directly because of limitations like this.

Comment: BUILD 2012 VS team was demoing better filtering for the studio test runner window.  It was not 100% obvious if that applied to all platforms or just windows 8.  Apparently that code base is very fragmented ;p

Answer (score 5):

If your unit test project is in a separate namespace, you could use the keyboard shortcut `CTRL+R, T` to run all tests in the current context (i.e. `namespace MyApp.Tests.Unit`). To do this place the cursor just after the opening curly brace in the namespace clause of any unit test class.

Comment: This is a good suggestion but the problem is that we have multiple unit test projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion but you won't like it.

Abandon MSTest entirely, while other unit test frameworks have been evolving MSTest as almost stopped in time. Yes, it has a major benefit of integrating directly with VS, but if I'm not mistaken that will change in VS 2011 which will provide native support for custom unit test runners integration.

*(Note: The stopped in time part may be not true because I confess not paying to much attention to MSTest since I used it sparingly with VS 2008)*

I use NUnit and separate my unit tests from the integration tests by using a different class library project. Then I automate the running of the tests using Gallio command line runner allowing me to configure separate scripts for running unit and integration tests.

Finally, personal opinions aside, I'm not sure but the [TestDriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/quickstart.aspx) plugin may have support for running tests with a specific category only, so you could check that.